# $f$ is an analytic function in $\mathbb C$. Prove or disprove that if $f(z)=f(3z)$ then $f(z)=C$, while $C$ is constant complex number.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$f$ is an analytic function in $\mathbb C$. Prove or disprove that if $f(z)=f(3z)$ then $f(z)=C$, while $C$ is constant complex number. I tried to disprove by trying to make $f(z)=e^{2\pi iz}$ this function does not equal constant because $f(0)=e^{2\pi i0}=e^0=1$ while $f(\frac{1}{2})=e^{2\pi i(\frac{1}{2})}=e^{\pi i}=-1$ , $f(0)\neq f(\frac{1}{2})$. but then I was skeptic about the condition $f(z)=f(3z)$. Is my function $f(z)=e^{2\pi iz}$ fulfills the condition $f(z)=f(3z)$? Same question as: "Is this equation correct:$$e^{2\pi iz}=e^{6\pi iz} $$??".

Comment: Do we know anything about $f$? Is it assumed to be continuous, for instance?

Comment: If $f$ is holomorphic, then you can prove it by Liouville’s Theorem.

Comment: Yes, f is analytic in all of the Complex field

Answer (score 3):

From the comments, $f$ is analytic in $\mathbb{C}$.

This implies $f$ is continuous, hence bounded in the unit disk by a positive number, say $B$. For all $z\in\mathbb{C}$, we may choose an integer $n$ such that $3^n>|z|$, hence $3^{-n}z$ lies in the unit disk. So from the assumption $f(z)=f(3z)$, $|f(z)|= |f(3^{-n}z)|\le B$. Since $f$ analytic and bounded in the whole complex plane, applying Liouville’s Theorem yields $f$ is constant.

By the way, $e^{2\pi iz}=e^{6\pi iz}$ is not correct for all $z$. For example, let $z=1/3$, then $e^{2\pi iz}= e^{2/3\cdot\pi i}=-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}i$, but $e^{6\pi iz} = e^{2\pi i} = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

My first answer was totally false. I thought that $f$ is complex periodic (as it is on the real line).

However, I found another way.

I propose this method because, as the properties of the function $f$ are really simple, there should be a simple way to solve the problem without the use of theorems.

Since $f$ is analytical, there exists the coefficients $\{a_n\}$ such that :

$$f(z)  = \sum^\infty_0 a_n z^n $$

Now, $f(z) = f(3z)$ :

$$\sum^\infty_0 a_n z^n = \sum^\infty_0 3^n a_n z^n := \sum^\infty_0 b_n z^n $$

by unicity of the coefficients, $$\forall n \in \mathbb N, a_n = b_n$$ then : $$\forall n > 0, a_n = 0 $$

Comment: but does not that mean that $f(z)=0$ for every $z$?

Comment: no, it means it is a constant @Jasmine. Because, the previous last equality says $$\forall n \colon a_n = b_n$$, and $$b_0 = a_0$$ so it is whatever constant you want :), which makes sense. Btw john's answer is exactly the same idea as mine's. I stil personnaly like mine's more because it is clear what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

A different but perhaps more visible or direct way to see that $f(z)$ must be constant is to note that $f(z) = f(3z)$ implies $|f’(z)| = 3|f’(3z)|$. Thus if $f’(z_0)\not=0$ for some $z_0\not=0$ then the derivative $f’$ blows up along the geometric sequence $z_0, z_0/3, z_0/9,\ldots$ which can’t happen for $f$ analytic. Thus $f’(z) = 0$ for all $z\not=0$ and indeed also for $z=0$, so $f$ is constant.

Comment: Interesting solution. To explain why it can’t happen, what came in my mind is that a complex function is complex differentiable iff it is indefinitely complex differentiable (so its derivative is continuous), which is also a proposition closely related to Cauchy’s integration theorem.

Comment: Yep, that’s what I had in mind too! Can’t have a derivative be continuous if it’s racing off the page 

Comment: what do you mean by : "$f'$ blows up along the geometric sequence"

Comment: Fair question - I mean that $\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty}|f(z_n)| = \infty$ for $z_n = z_0/3^n$.

Comment: Sorry, Maybe I forgot a theorem, but why what you have wrote in the last comment can’t happen for f analytic?

Comment: It can’t happen because if $f$ is analytic, then so is $f’$. And if $f’$ is analytic then in particular it is continuous (indeed so is its absolute value $|f’|$). But then for any continuous function $g$ we know $\text{lim}_{z\to a}g(z) = g(a)$ for all $a$. So it can’t be infinite

Comment: It’s worth making clear that since \text{lim}_{n\to\infty}z_0/3^n = 0$, the limit I wrote above ($\text{lim}_{n\to\infty}|f’(z_n)|$) is therefore equal to $\text{lim}_{z\to 0}|f’(z)|$. Hopefully this ties things together?

Comment: I didn’t write all this limit stuff in my answer because I just wanted to stress the essential idea which is that the relation $|f’(z)| = 3|f’(3z)|$ implies that $|f’|$ is going off to infinity as $z$ goes to $0$ (if there is any $z_0$ with $f’(z_0)\not=0$). Since $|f’|$ is continuous, that shouldn’t be happening. And so $f’$ is zero everywhere.

Comment: Wow thank you so mush, now I have a similar question, f is analytic in all $\mathbb C$ and we know that $|f(z)-f(2z)|$ less or equal to 10. Which is better for me to use, the sums or the differential way in proving?

Comment: No problem! Ah, now this is a great question. Let me make one point first: for the first question you asked, you’ll notice that all we really used was that $f$ had a continuous derivative - we didn’t really use the fact that $f$ was analytic in any essential way, except to say it had a continuous derivative, and then we got the answer from there. For this second question, it’s actually going to be essential that $f$ is analytic, because there are examples of $f$ satisfying this new condition and having continuous derivative which are *not* constant. However, those examples won’t be analytic.

Comment: An example would be any bump function with height at most 10.

Comment: So to prove that $f$ is constant in this case, we’ll really need a theorem from complex analysis. And Liouville’s is the one we want - basically, if you think about restricting your function to the annulus with inner radius 1 and outer radius 2 then because of the relation $|f(z) - f(2z)| \leq 10$, we see that $f$ actually attains all of it’s possible output values on this annulus. But the annulus is compact, so $|f|$ has a maximum on the annulus. But since $f$ is entire and achieves all its values on the annulus, this maximum is actually a maximum on all of $\bb{C}$.

Comment: So $f$ is a bounded entire function, hence constant by Liouville. So in this case, we really see a difference in the behavior of analytic functions compared to just smooth ones.

Comment: Sorry, the second to last comment is more complicated than necessary, and ultimately wrong actually. Instead, let $g(z) = f(z) - f(2z)$. Then $g$ is an entire function and $|g(z)| \leq 10$ so $g$ is bounded, hence constant by Liouville. Thus $f(z) = f(2z) + c$ for $c$ the constant. Differentiating then yields $f’(z) = 2f’(2z)$ and so now you could proceed as we did before. The point remains that this time we really needed analyticity to use Liouville and the bump function example illustrates why it’s necessary.